# Flutter SelectableText no Select All option on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm using `SelectableText.rich()` widget to allow user to copy the displayed text.
On Android the default options in toolbar are Copy and Select All - I can also customize it.
On iOS the default option appears to be only Copy and setting `ToolbarOptions` doesn't change that (only when I set copy to false, it disappears).
My goal is to display Copy and Select All options on both Android and iOS.
Am I missing something or is it some kind of a bug?

```
SelectableText.rich(
                          TextSpan(children: [
                            TextSpan(
                              text: "Name\n",
                              style:
                                  TextStyles.getDetailViewLabelStyle(context),
                            ),
                            TextSpan(
                              text: projectName,
                              style:
                                  TextStyles.getDetailViewContentStyle(context),
                            )
                          ]),
                          toolbarOptions:
                              const ToolbarOptions(copy: true, selectAll: true),
                        ),
```

Comment: I found [this closed issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83700) on the official repo. I suggest opening a similar issue so that the bug is fixed, as the last one was closed due to inactivity of the poster. In short, this is a flutter bug, so while it may be possible to achieve the same functionality by other means, it should be fixed on the official repository.